Drag vs Lift, Airplanes vs Sailboats
We know that sailplanes need big span, thin airfoil profile and twist (flying wings) to have a decent L/D ratio and fly more distance while a short take off distance STOL planes need (besides noisy and faulty engine) thick airfoils with flat surface and multielement wing (front slats and rear flaperons)
Do you think that sailboats are more related to drag reduction as sailplanes or to lift increase as STOL (as they are examples of both cruising and take off mode respectively)?
And in the case of sail vs keel?

As they have bouyancy, one might say that sailboats would favor drag reduction like sail planes.  STOL slats and flaps (see airliners) are only needed for takeoff and landing.  Airliners fold them up minimize drag in cruise.  See clipper and schooner to see how sailboats reduce drag.

Yes i forgot about the difference between aircraft take off and cruising, both for thrust requirements and lift and drag, and still this could apply in sailboats to low and high wind thrust scenarios or wind angle as upwind

Wind mills are another one.  The old style ones were more like STOL, but the newer ones incorporate aerodynamic (drag) improvements, enabling higher speeds in lighter winds.

Yes, these HAWT wind blades are high span and aspect ratio (that otherwise create noise and disrupts birds) that probably look more for rpm in low wind days. Wind turbines can be also VAWT and usually short span and aspect ratio as savonious that seek torque instead rpm and they can power any appliance (pumps, compressors, washing machines, drill, lathe,etc) with that torque without electricity

Since wind is free one might go for the max torque.  Gears can be added for PTO RPM.

One of the real keys here is Reynolds number.  At around 200,000 one can take advantage of lifting properties and sail even faster than the wind (iceboats).  In light airs,  it is probably best to hang out as much sail as possible, especially since boat speed (with water drag) will be less than wind speed.  But schooners usually sail circles around square riggers.

I think this is related to the boat speed related to it's weight and sail area and wind speed, so in low wind the drag is an issue while with strong wind the lift is an advantage.
The keel, daggerboard, rudder, leeboard and rest of hydrodynamic appendages create heel in the same direction of the sails, in the water the high pressure is leeward while in sails is in winward side and do the keel ballast try to counteract this combined heeling.
In a sailboat the drag is more predominant in the submerged appendages rather than sail drag
On the other hand the hydrodynamic lift is more important in upwind to avoid leeway (drifting) with the appendages "lateral resistance" and so for hydrodynamic appendages to increase lift in upwind and reduce drag we need aspect ratio rather than span while sails usually try to increase span to access to more wind power gradient and twist to reduce sail tip turbulence drag
In upwind the hydrodynamic appendages can be asymmetric airfoil to increase lift against leeway
On the other hand asymmetric flexible wingsails also create closer angles of attack in windward compared to common sails
This is a matter of the energy input, similar to sailplanes and engine planes so in low wind airfoil drag is more an issue and in high wind an airfoil with lift gives an advantage
